# How do I remove a block (pygame)?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

I`m having trouble with this. The character is supposed to collide with the block (coin) in order to get the points, and then the block should disappear, but it is not working, so I keep getting the points over and over again.

```
block_hit_list=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.coin_list, False)
for block in block_hit_list:
    block_hit_list.remove(block)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean to remove the collided blocks from the coins in the level. To do that, change the for loop to this:

```
for block in block_hit_list:
    self.level.coin_list.remove(block)
```

Alternatively, just set the `dokill` argument of `spritecollide` to True (thanks @snark):

```
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.coin_list, True)
```

Comment: Or just set dokill to True